# Excel Find first not blank, then the next?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

(system= windows 7 excel 2013)

I’m trying to make a formula that will show me the trend in selling prices.

My system shows me everytime a new price have been made, but if a new price have not been made is just show nothing.

But to show the development using a graph, I need the value to continue and only change if there is a new price, and the continue with the price

Below is a ex:

The columns are month and year and the rows are product lines. In the first line all the month/year should be 1251. And in the 5 row is should start being 299 then change to 179 for the next columns.

I have tried to use this formula `INDEX = (Q3: AD3; MATCH (FALSE; ISBLANK (Q3: AD3), 0))` as an array formula, and it sort of works, but not completely.

[image: Pic of ex.]

all help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if() statement to check the update - if true return the update value and if false return the previous value.

Sorry on a smartphone so can't test but something like :

IF(update<>"",update,previous)
Or
IF(update=0,previous,update)

Depends how you see the logic and what is in the update cell if there is no value...